# Issues with implementing shadow mapping produces weird results

Tags: glsl, shadows, shadow-mapping, vulkan

This is my first attempt in implementing shadow mapping. I am using right hand coordinate system and my projection matrices are producing z values from 0 to 1.
I've decided first to use orthogonal projection matrix for shadows:

```
mat4 LightProj = Ortho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 20);
mat4 LightView = LookAt(-4, 4, -2);
```

This is how I produce my data for shadows. Vertex Shader:

```
mat4 Bias = mat4
    (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0
     );
    Out.ShadowPos  = Bias * WorldUpdate.LightProj * WorldUpdate.LightView * Out.Pos;
```

Fragment shader:

```
float GetShadow(vec4 PositionInLightSpace, vec3 Normal, vec3 LightDir)
{
    float  Bias = 0.0; //05; //max(0.05 * (1.0 - dot(Normal, LightDir)), 0.005);
    vec3   ProjPos     = PositionInLightSpace.xyz / PositionInLightSpace.w;
    float  ShadowDepth = texture(ShadowMap, ProjPos.xy).x;
    float  ObjectDepth = ProjPos.z;
    float  Result      = (ObjectDepth - Bias) > ShadowDepth ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    return Result;
}

    float Shadow  = GetShadow(In.ShadowPos, Normal, LightDir);
    vec3 Ambient  = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) * 0.2;

    OutputColor = vec4(Ambient + Shadow * Light, 1.0) * In.Col;
```

At first glance everything looks fine. Even generated shadow map:
[image]
But the results looks really way off the correct solution:
[image]
How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I was using vulkan, it should be like this:

```
mat4 Bias = mat4
    (0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
     0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
     0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

The thing is that in vulkan everything being rendered from bottom to top and therefor in my renderer Y is reversed.
That's it.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained why this change fixes the problem.